# JMeter's ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt vs ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.usr

Tags: jmeter

When I click "HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder"'s <kbd>Start</kbd> button, there is a popup telling me that the cert is created in the bin folder:

[image]

In the bin folder I see two files:

- ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt
- ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.usr

Both files are 1326 bytes and are BeyondCompare states that they are **identical**:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Sure, 'ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt' holds the cert info. But why does JMeter generate two identical files?

What's the purpose of 'ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.usr'?

---

<sup>• Tested on v2.13 r1665067.</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt**

- This certificate is for browsers Firefox,Chrome and Internet explorer.
- List item

**ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.usr**

- This certificate is for browser opera.

Reference 1  : [Jmeter Recording and Certificates](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

Reference 2 : [Jmeter Certificates](http://qnalist.com/questions/4534395/ssl-proxy-recording-does-not-work-with-opera-yet)

Comment: Odd, but the files are ***identical***. I can understand if FF/Chrome/IE uses one format and Opera uses another, but these files are bit-for-bit equal, wouldn't generating one be sufficient?

Comment: Yes I have also checked files has equal data. you can try by deleting .usr and import .ctr to browser and see if it works or not..